# Integrals, and even and odd functions

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

I am looking at a proof and got stuck on a part with an integral.  I tried to simplify the problem as much as possible, I hope I did not omit any potential helpful information.  I have an even function $K()$ and I taking the integral of it and the product of a $\sin()$ squared.  What I am confused about is that $K(0)$ was pulled out of the integral in one of the steps.  Here is the integral,

$$\left ( \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{K(x)}{x}sin(x) dx\right )^2 $$

Then on the next line of the proof I see:

$$  K^2(0)\left (\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x}sin(x) dx\right )^2 (1+ o(1))$$

And then the proof continues.  I am not sure while we are able to take the $K()$ function out.  My suspicion is it has to do with some property about even and odd functions?  Suggestions and help are appreciated!

Comment: I haven't had much time to look at this, but this is at least provable for $\pi$ periodic continuous functions via Lobachevsky's Dirichlet integral formula.